# Read Event Log From Newest to Oldest

Tags: c#, .net, windows, event-log

I have written a short program to establish the uptime for remote PC's using the event log messages which are posted at startup and shutdown. Currently the logic is :

```
  foreach (eventlogentry)
  {
       if (entryTime > OldestTime)
       {
            if (entry = Startup)
            {
                 addOnTime(entry.Time);
            }
            if (entry = Shutdown)
            {
                 addOffTime(entry.Time);
            }
       }
  }
```

"OldestTime" define how far to scan backwards in time....

I would like to know if there is anyway to easily ammend my program to read the events from newest to oldest?

It's reading remote event logs and its taking a while for this function to run, as it starts at the end and reads forward.

I know this because I added a "else" block to the first "if" to break out of the foreach block, if the entry isnt within the timespan we are looking for and the program stop's at the first event it reads.

Comment: How are you reading the event log? You may be able to change the way that you read the log so that it processes it in a different order but by the time you get to this point in the code the read has already taken place and so you cannot change the ordering.

Comment: are these logs text files?  If so can you not load them into a list first and then read it from the end you want to?

Comment: What API are you using to query these remote even log entries? Is there maybe an API you can use to request only entries newer than OldestTime? That way the order shouldn't really matter.

Answer (score 5):

It has been a while since you asked this question, but i ran into the same problem and found a solution.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

EventLog events = new EventLog("Application", System.Environment.MachineName);
foreach (EventLogEntry entry in  events.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>().Reverse())
{
    //Do your tasks
}
```

This awnser still is not as fast as to just enumerate it forward but it is a bit more elegant than using a loop to copy items to a list.

@leinad13, for your application you need to change System.Environment.MachineName to a string with the name of the computer you want the events from and change "Application" to the log you want to see. I think "System" in your case.

Comment: EventLogEntryCollection supports indexing. It would be best to loop over it  with a reverse integer iterator ie `for (int i=collection.Count;i > 0;i--) { collection[i].whatever}`

Answer (score 0):

Your best solution may be to move the data into a list and then reverse the order of that. Something like the following:

```
EventLog eventLog = new EventLog();
eventLog.Log = myEventLog;
var eventList = new List<EventLogEntry>();

foreach(EventLogEntry entry in eventLog.Entries)
{
      eventList.Add(entry);
}

eventList.Reverse();
```

That should get the data in the reverse order, i.e. latest first, and then you can just process it as before but this time exit the loop when you hit a date before the oldest time.

Its not an ideal solution as you are still processing the whole log but it may be worth trying out to see if you get an improvement in performance

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who got here to just get the last logs since some process started (deployment or something like that).

It is not necessary to iterate the whole list. This will get the last X events:

```
private static EventLogEntry[] GetLastEventLogs(int numberOfEntries, bool ascending = false)
{
    List<EventLogEntry> events = new List<EventLogEntry>();
    EventLog eLog = new EventLog("Application", Environment.MachineName);
    int i = eLog.Entries.Count - numberOfEntries;
    for (int t = (i + numberOfEntries) - 1; t >= i; t--)
        events.Add(eLog.Entries[t]);

    if (ascending)
        events.Reverse();

    return events.ToArray();
}
```

Personally I prefer using a start date. Keep `DateTime.Now` in a variable in case something fails. When it fails use it to get only relevant logs...

```
private static EventLogEntry[] GetLastEventLogs(DateTime fromTime, bool ascending = false)
{
    List<EventLogEntry> events = new List<EventLogEntry>();
    EventLog eLog = new EventLog("Application", Environment.MachineName);

    for (int t = eLog.Entries.Count - 1; t >= 0; t--)
    {
        EventLogEntry e = eLog.Entries[t];
        if (e.TimeGenerated > fromTime)
            break;
        events.Add(e);
    }

    if (ascending)
        events.Reverse();

    return events.ToArray();
}
```