# How can I find the index value of the last item in the Application EventLog? (As it doesn't seem to be Entries.Count - 1)

Tags: c#, event-log

**Problem Context**

My application needs to look at some entries in the EventLog whenever a new entry is written to the Application log, in order to check if the originated with a specific application.

To do this, I have a 'typical' event handler (`private void eventLog__EntryWritten(object sender, System.Diagnostics.EventWrittenEventArgs e)`) which then calls a method to `parseApplicationLogEntries()`.

My application is looking for entries since a certain time. So, to do so -

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog log = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog("Application"); 

// The firstLog since the startTime defaults to the last index 
// (since an entry has just been written to the application log 
/// there must have been at least one since the start time) 
int firstLog = log.Entries.Count - 1; 

// Enter a for loop from the last entry in the log, backwards to 0 
for (int entry = log.Entries.Count - 1; entry > 0; entry --) 
{ 
    // Gets the time the log entry was written to compare to the start time
    DateTime logEntryTimeWritten = log.Entries[entry].TimeWritten; 

    // Compares the time the log entry was written with the start time
    if (logEntryTimeWritten < startTime) 
    {
        // If the time the log entry was written was *before* the start time
        // then our first log entry is the one after this, so save the 
        // index of the first log entry, then break out of the for loop
        firstLog = entry + 1; 
        break; 
    } 
}
```

**Problem**

My problem is, when the EventLog reaches a certain size (e.g. hits its maximum) then this starts causing errors. Unhandled IndexOutOfRangeException errors occur. As this index which is out of range was less than the `Count` of the `Entries`, I was confused...

Now, I have a theory as to why these are occurring. The default behavior for Application Logs is to "Overwrite events as needed" once the maximum size is reached. This makes me think they must be adding entries with new indexes and removing old entries (or something) which means some of my indexes which are > `Count` do not have an entry there... (Please forgive me if this a misguided theory)

Obviously I should be handling any case where an index is not found (which I will add, so it just skips over any out of range). However, if my theory is correct, how do I find the index value of the most recent entry in the event log if it is not equal to `Count - 1`? (If my theory is incorrect, what could be going on here?)

Thanks!

Comment: take a look at this and maybe you can incorporate some techniques along with some more meaningful logic as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023472/read-event-log-from-newest-to-oldest

Comment: Thanks! I'll check that out. Does anyone know if my assumption / theory about how the event log overwriting works correct?

Comment: you need to understand as well what the `IndexOutOfRangeException` also have you stepped thru the code..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE The `IndexOutOfRangeException` only occurs when the EventLog is close to its maximum size and then only at random.

Comment: Like I said earlier you need to step thru the code and pin point where the error is actually happening and why ..perhaps you can create a new Event log Entry with a smaller subset and then the error may become more obvious.. perhaps you are you need to rethink how you are wanting to access the last entry and or most current..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to access the EventLog in this way to review the newest entries.

Instead of calling a method to iterate through the EventLog each time a new Entry is written, it is simpler (and safer) to access the Entry more directly using the event handler which triggers each time an Entry is written.

```
private void eventLog_Application_EntryWritten(object sender, EntryWrittenEventArgs e)
{
    // Process e.Entry    
}
```